How to display specific data into modal component
I try to get file detail data and pass it into the modal component, but I don't know how. Does anyone know how to display file data into the modal when click <x-dropdown-link File Detail in Laravel? Thanks!!
@foreach ($files as $file)
    <tr class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
        <td class="px-6 py-4">
            <!-- Settings Dropdown -->
            <div class="hidden sm:flex sm:items-center sm:ms-6">
                <x-dropdown align="right" width="48">
                    <x-slot name="trigger">
                        <button>
                            <div class="ms-1">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="none"
                                    viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                    <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="3"
                                        d="M12 6h.01M12 12h.01M12 18h.01" />
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                    </x-slot>

                    <x-slot name="content">
                        <x-dropdown-link x-on:click.prevent="$dispatch('open-modal', 'confirm-user-deletion')">
                            {{ __('File Detail') }}
                            </button>
                        </x-dropdown-link>
                    </x-slot>
                </x-dropdown>
            </div>
            <x-modal name="confirm-user-deletion" :show="$errors->userDeletion->isNotEmpty()" focusable>
                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700">
                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between p-4 md:p-5 border-b rounded-t dark:border-gray-600">
                        <h3 class="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                            {{ __('File Infomation') }}
                        </h3>
                        <button x-on:click="$dispatch('close')" type="button"
                            class="end-2.5 text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm w-8 h-8 ms-auto inline-flex justify-center items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white"
                            data-modal-hide="authentication-modal">
                            <svg class="w-3 h-3" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none"
                                viewBox="0 0 14 14">
                                <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                                    stroke-width="2" d="m1 1 6 6m0 0 6 6M7 7l6-6M7 7l-6 6" />
                            </svg>
                            <span class="sr-only">Close modal</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Modal body -->
                    <div class="p-4 md:p-5">
                        <form class="space-y-4" action="#">
                            <div>
                                <label for="fileName"
                                    class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">File
                                    Name</label>
                                <input
                                    class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-600 dark:border-gray-500 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white"
                                    readonly />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label for="fileSize"
                                    class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Size
                                    (KB)
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-600 dark:border-gray-500 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white"
                                    readonly />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label for="fileSize"
                                    class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Type
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-600 dark:border-gray-500 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white"
                                    readonly />
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit"
                                class="w-full text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">Save
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </x-modal>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach


I try using JavaScript and it work but I cannot create a function change file name in modal so I looking other way.
